# Test if a Mersenne number is prime using the Lucas-Lehmer test in Python-using iteration and conditional logic

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

Test if a Mersenne number is prime using the Lucas-Lehmer test. It can be done by first write a function that generates the sequence used in the test. Given a Mersenne number with exponent   , the sequence can be defined as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMx6e.png)

Write a function that accepts the exponent    of a Mersenne number and returns the Lucas-Lehmer sequence up to  =−2  (inclusive). Remember that the modulo operation is implemented in Python as %.

Use your function to calculate the Lucas-Lehmer series for $p = 17$ , and the result should follow the format below:

```
ll_result = [4] * 16
```

My code is as follows:

```
ll_result = []
def lucas_lehmer(p):
    if p == 2:
         return 4
    for p in range(3,p):
        return (lucas_lehmer(p-1)**2-2)%((2**p)-1)    
    ll_result.append(ll_result())

lucas_lehmer(17)
```

And the output of my code is: 0

Please help me to identify my mistakes. Thanks

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209609/lucas-lehmer-primality-test-with-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lucas-Lehmer primality test with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209609/lucas-lehmer-primality-test-with-python)